# Adobe Illustrator export as .jpeg vs Photoshop save as .jpeg

Tags: image, photoshop, photo, adobe-illustrator

I have a illustrator file where it has a Photoshop file linked and some added text.
when I export as .jpeg the photo gets a little pixelated compared to when I save as .jpeg from Photoshop.
why is it so, is it because Photoshop has an Quality 12, compared to Illustrator which only gives 10.
any ideas

P.S. I used in Illustrator, Compression: Baseline (Standard), Resolution: 300 ppi, Anti-Aliasing: Type Optimized

Comment: This isn't on topic here. Check the pixel size of the images though.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Oh I didn't realize, whats the place to ask this type of question within the stack-exchange network? BTW, pixle size is the same 300ppi

Comment: That's not the pixel size. Check the actual width/height in pixels in each image

Comment: Th pixels are not the same because I resized it to fit to a smaller format, The photoshop was '3184 x 2100' and the Illustator is '3000 x 2400', The thing is that I linked the same Photoshop file, which was 10.613 inch at 300 dpi, but in illustrator I re-sized it to 'smaller' to a 10 inch width, so it shouldn't have lost any pixels, but still it went pixelated, but now when I imported the Photoshop file as it is without re-sizing it, it was as clear as the Photoshop jpeg, intersting

Answer (score 0):

Illustrator's native storage is SVG , a vector format , while Photoshop uses bitmaps, where jpeg is one of its native languages.

Basically people who use Illustrator most of the time store in vector format, and illustrator does not have a good conversion engine for vector   -> jpeg.

Photoshop renders vectors to bitmaps, like any browser does, and these are easy to convert to .jpeg.

*conspiracy theory* Adobe wants graphic designers to buy both Illustrator and Photoshop.

Other software to consider may be paint.NET which is free , and, I think, can handle all the image types and file types you are using ( the drawback being - far fewer image manipulation tools ).

Comment: I like the conspiracy theory

Comment: If you read the 4th comment on question, you will see that it was due to re-sizing the Photoshop file in Illustrator, even it was re-sized to smaller. in fact when I just open the .PSD (Photoshop) file in Illustrator and export it as it is, it will remain the full quality